# How to view vendor information of my NIC?

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, command, nic

How to get the vendor information of my NIC on top of Ubuntu? I wanna get its vendor, type and things like that? Any shell commands available? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11):

Try something like this -

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

**OR**

```
sudo ethtool -i eth0
```